# way to changes displayed names using MappingJacksonJsonView

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a POJO class **Result**,

```
public class Result {
    private String someName;
    private String someOtherName;
}
```

which is returned in my model and displayed as a json in the output:

```
{"result":
    {"someName":"value",
    "someOtherName":"value"}}
```

I can not find a way to display them as **some_name** and **some_other_name**, do you know what kind of mapping has to be set up to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@JsonProperty` annotation

```
public class Result {
    @JsonProperty(value = "some_name")
    private String someName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "some_other_name")
    private String someOtherName;
}
```

The `value` attribute javadoc states

> Defines name of the logical property, i.e. JSON object field name to
>   use for the property. If value is empty String (which is the default),
>   will try to use name of the field that is annotated. Note that there
>   is no default name available for constructor arguments, meaning that
>   Empty String is not a valid value for constructor arguments.